# Algorithm to assign workers to work area

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to assign workers to workplaces with a mix of different tasks and workloads.

1. There are several workplaces (let's say factories: F1, F2)
2. Within that workplace, there is a waiting workload of different task types, each task in various quantities (let's say in F1, we need to make 10 pcs of product X, 20 pcs of product Y, and 30 pcs of product Z; the other factory F2 has different workload)
3. Each worker can perform one or more workload type (W1 can make product X, W2 can make products X and Y, W3 can make Y and Z), for the sake of simplicity, we assume that all workers are of equal skill and the products take equal amonut of time to make.
4. The algorithm has to work for any non-zero number of workplaces, task types and workers. Obviously in case there are more workplaces than workers, the algorithm would have to be run in iterations. When the work in one workplace is finished, the worker would be rebalanced to a different workplace with some work remaining.

Is there an efficient algorithm, that can assign the workers to workplaces to minimize the production time? I thied to fit it to Hungarian algorithm, but I think it's not the same problem.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the problem with using the Hungarian algorithm is that the doing the whole thing may take more than one iteration. Perhaps you could find an optimal schedule for N iterations if you fed the Hungarian algorithm with a version of the problem in which there were N copies of each worker.

In this case you could try N=1,2,4... until finding an N that worked and then binary chop between this N and the highest N tried that did not work (N/2) to find the minimum value of N for which the problem could be solved.